# Java:Android exclude packages with dependencies in final compiled file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, conditional-compilation

I have this problem in Android/Eclipse.

I´m working in Android Project , this one has to be configured in different ways for different customers,  this configurations are not similar(very different methods) between them.

The code is shared in 90%, but each customer has his own requirements.

Each customer has a package with diferent and multiple classes.

I would like only include package of choiced customer in the final compiled file.

But i have conditional object creation in my shared code, and i have to join all package for compiling.

More or less is this (Example)

```
//import every  customer packages
import com.project.customer_1
import com.project.customer_2
import com.project.customer_3
…..
import com.project.customer_98
import com.project.customer_99
……..
final static int customer=2; //Define the customer for this compilation
………

if (customer==1) { //unreachable code
customerClass1 customer1=new customerClass1();
customer1.method1_1;
customer1.method1_2;
customer1.method1_3;
}

else if (customer==2) {
customerClass2 customer2=new customerClass2();
customer2.method2_1;
customer2.method2_2;
customer2.method2_3;
}
…….//unreachable code
else if (customer==98) {//unreachable code
customerClass98 customer98=new customerClass98();
customer98.method98_1;
customer98.method98_2;
customer98.method98_3;
}
else if (customer==99{//unreachable code
customerClass99 customer99=new customerClass99();
customer99.method99_1;
customer99.method99_2;
customer99.method99_3;
}
............
```

Is clear when customer=X, the other choices  are unreachable code. I would like  exclude other customer packages/classes than customer is choiced in compiled file. But exist dependency in code

Note: For me is not valid comment code, neither reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do it in way you've described.

You should create additional level of abstraction to access data/logic specific to customers. And move that customer specific logic/data to separate libraries/projects.

To work with separated customer projects, your abstraction level should use dynamic class loading.

**Edit**. If you can't refactor your project, you can create Proguard config files for each customer to remove unreachable code.

Comment: @titgar, a hint that you are in the right direction will be that you don't need to change the source code to build different packages, but only changing the build commands

Comment: pbespechnyi, I understand you think i would must find the way to use reflection in my case?.

Comment: @titgar, yes, to dynamically load classes and create their instances you should you reflection.

Comment: @pbespechnyi, yes... i used reflection in other projects, but in this, the methods of customers have nothing to do ones with each others. for instance, in "task" button 1 customer read a file, the other make a math calc......

Comment: @titgar, that is why you need additional level of abstraction. Create interfaces (to hide customer implementation details) in `core` project, and implement them for each customer in another project/lib. Then, use unified interface to work with customer specific logic.

Comment: @pbespechnyi, and use statements(by customer) in _core_ for use one of other method, i suppose....

Comment: @titgar, create `Action` and `ActionFactory` interfaces and Actions enum with all possible actions in `core` project. Implement `ActionFactory` in `cust1` and create appropriate action mappings (i.e. `BUTTON1_ACT -> Cust1ButtonClickAction`). Load implementation of `ActionFactory` using `reflection` and get action for `cust1` and then execute it. Please note, I know nothing about your project, I've described first that came to my mind.

Comment: Thanks, i´ll think about that.